# How to define macros for paths to be used by biber?

Tags: macros, bibtex, biber

I want to use a shortcut to define the paths of my bibtex files and I'm  using biblatex and biber.

I would like something  like:

```
 \addbibresource{\myPath{biblio.bib}}
```

I tried in several ways i.e.

```
 \def\myDirPath{/home/user/directory/}


 \newcommand{\myPathA}[1] {\myDirPath#1}            % A
 \DeclareRobustCommand{\myPathB}[1] {\myDirPath#1}  % B
 \def\absPathC#1{\myDirPath#1}                      % C
```

then I run

```
 pdflatex mytex
 biber mytex
```

and it gives in any of the above cases:

```
 ERROR - Cannot find '/home/user/directory/{biblio.bib}'!
```

It seems latex inserts an additional pair of braces, 
what's wrong with my code?
Should I define my macros in a different way?

Comment: I just found a mistake in my code which coused the problem. Both the option A and C works but not the B.
Herbert answer add a space to the path causing an error. Should I cancel the question since it was based on a mistake?

Comment: Why not simply `\addbibresource{\myDirPath biblio.bib}`?

Comment: @egreg I tried with your suggestion, biber keeps the space and writes `ERROR - Cannot find '/home/user/directory/ biblio.bib'!`. It is for this reason I wanted to define a macro with arguments, it should better manage  the spaces " " in the paths. Actually, now %A and %C options work quite well.

Comment: Probably `biblatex` is cleverer than I and uses some protection for spaces not being gobbled. Options A and C are essentially equivalent; option B surely can't work, because it doesn't work by “pure expansion”. Another option could be `\myDirPath/biblio.bib` if a trailing `/` is missing in `\myDirPath` (or even if it isn't, probably).

Comment: @egreg Yes, the last one works both with and without `/` and it's really the simplest one. I should have thought it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
\expandafter\addbibresource\expandafter{\myPath biblio.bib}
```

or define

```
\edef\myFile{\myPath biblio.bib}
\addbibresource{\myFile}
```

Comment: Hi Herbert, thank you. I tried your suggestion but it actually add a space between the directory path and the file. Biber is not able to find the file.

Comment: try again with my edited answer