Bibliography input paths
We can manually modify and add to the input paths for .tex files with \def\input@path{} during runtime, so that we don't have to enter full paths when using \input. Can the same be done for biblatex/biber so that I don't need to prefix paths when using the \addbibresource command?
Use-case: my organization has shared .bib files on the network drive.

maybe try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191055/36296

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm looking for a more elegant solution than that. I would rather develop a command that specifies a path, and then I'm free to add .bib files.

just add the folder to the site wide BIBINPUTS path
